# Configure minimal Log4j2 in parallel to existing SLF4J&Logback

Tags: log4j2

We have more than 200 Spring Boot microservices, using Logback as their default logging framework through SLF4j as API. It is not possible to switch this large amount of services to use Log4j2 easily. Therefore and for a very special use-case I would like to use the asynchronous features in Log4j2 only.

Unfortunately the automatic configuration of Log4j2 always configures the `SLF4LoggingContextFactory` which uses the Logback implementation in the background.
My attempts to configure Log4j2 independently of the Logback framework seems not to work.

My questions are:

1. How can I stop Log4j2 to do the default configuration? (static initializer in the class `LogManager`)
2. How can I just configure one logger in an asynchronous way to send log events via HTTP to a REST API?

I know that programmatic configuration is not recommended by the Log4j2 team, but I could live with any changes in the future. And maybe an API can be added that allows such changes without setting VM parameters or messing around with internal classes.

Answer (score 1):

The original idea to re-configure Log4j2 was not good, as it would have broken the logging for all dependencies that use the Log4j2 API internally. The `SLF4JLoggingContextFactory` makes sure that all those logs get redirected to whatever SLF4J has configured (usually Logback in case of a Spring Boot application).

So the hint from a comment above to create multiple `LoggingContextFactory` instances was leading me into the right direction.

The following class implements a very simple logger using the Log4j2 sub-system, completely independent of the rest of the application:

```java
public class MyLogger {
    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext context;
    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger;

    static {
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector selector = new org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector();
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory factory = new org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory(selector);
        context = factory.getContext(MyLogger.class.getName(), null,null, true);
        logger = context.getLogger("MyLogger");
    }

    public static void info(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

The good thing is that all dependencies, using Log4j2 as their logging framework, will still use the `SLF4LoggingContextFactory` and thus all logs are sent to the Logback sub-system. Only the special loggers, created by my instance of the `Log4jContextFactory`, will use the Log4j2 backend.

I know that this depends on internal Log4j2 APIs, but because it is wrapped into a class `MyLogger`, any changes of the internal APIs can be hidden.

Comment: I'm not sure if you care about caller information but it will be incorrect with this implementation as the caller will always be the MyLogger class, not the caller of your API.  That could be fairly easily fixed. In fact, if you wanted that I would recommend using the Log4j's LogBuilder so you could inject the location information into each event.  Other than that this is a good way to handle your problem.

Answer (score 0):

SLF4JLoggerContextFactory is part of log4j-to-slf4j which routes all Log4j API calls to SLF4J. At this time there is no way to tell Log4j that for some arbitrary logging calls it should use a different implementation. Although Log4j can discover multiple implementations it provides no logic to choose more than one.

If you only have a single use case why is it a problem to switch that one service to use Log4j 2? It should require no code changes.

Comment: The Logback configuration is quite complex and the "very special use case" does not mean "a single microservice", it is a single use-case in all microservice. I want to provide an additional library that each microservice uses to send logs via HTTP asynchronously to a logging sink. So the idea is to leave the Logback logging untouched and just add a library to send logs to Azure Log Analytics (for example), using an asynchronous HTTP Appender.

Comment: While it would be possible to modify LogManager to support multiple LoggerContextFactory implementations and allow a custom factory selector there are many other Jira issues I would probably prioritize above this. Also, any code that would want to take advantage of this would have to use the Log4j API since SLF4J also only supports a single implementation.